# php session sometimes not avaliable after passing to another domain

Tags: php, session, ssl

I run a website which can be reached through different domains: domainname.de, domainname.ch, domainname.at, domainname.es etc. ...

When my customer wants to pay we gets to a payment page which is of course https secured. Due to server limitations I am only allowed to have one SSL Certificate which I only put on one domain: domainname-secure.com.

Because I charge different prices I need to know which domain the user belongs to, so when redirecting to domainname-secure.com I save the domain (e.g. domainname.de) in the session variable `$_SESSION['domain_default']` and pass the sessionID by adding `session_id=[session_id]` as a get parameter.

Then I check I take `$_GET['session_id']` and run the follow command to have the session available on the domainname-secure.com:

```
session_id($_GET['session_id']);

session_start();
```

When I test it myself, it works perfectly fine but I make a log entry when somebody gets to domainname-secure.com and has not have set `$_SESSION['domain_default']`.

This occurs several times a day but I really have no clue why this does not work! I am testing it again and again from many different links but for me it works perfectly fine.

Can some of you imagine why it sometimes does not work?

Is it not "good" or insecure to pass the session ID to another domain and is it not always readable after redirecting?

I know it is hard for you to determain a mistake but I am searching for some know issues with session or maybe a tip how to do it in a better way?

Comment: Does your server setup include the suhosin patchset?

Comment: Why don't you just add the domain to the user in the database? Then you would not need this unnecessary complicated setup.

Comment: @jeroen He wants to get the data he has stored in `$_SESSION`. That's why he's passing the session_id through get. I'd assume he's getting some other info from the `$_SESSION` variable besides the origin domain. Otherwise he could just put the domain name in the `$_GET` params as well.

Comment: @Mihai Stancu No, `$_GET` can be manipulated and if a user belongs to a domain, the db is the place to set that. Apart from that, you would not want your client to hop to another site to get a lower price...

Comment: Thank you for your answers so far!

@jeroen but I still have other infos in the SESSION which I need access to

Answer (score 2):

Session are administered by PHP on a *per domain basis* meaning they don't mix domains intentionally.

If you would be using another session storage mechanism such as writing into the database or using memcached sessions you'd be able to overcome this limitation.

There are two approaches if you want to be able to access the session info when changing domains either:

- Don't use PHP's $_SESSION, setup your own session management with memcached/redis/sql;

Or:

- Use PHP's $_SESSION, but when transferring from one domain to another serialize the data in $_SESSION and put it somewhere accessible from both domains like sql;

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But isn't that the reason why the session_id can be passed (besides the fact that cookies could be disabled) via get parameter to overcome this limitation?

Comment: Nope, this is the reason why *even if* you pass the session_id through $_GET you won't be able to access another domains session files - they are separated.

Comment: But it works for me.. I only get error message that it does not work for somebody else. This isnt browser related, is it?

Comment: Post the error message then. And no, it isn't browser related unless you're using $_COOKIES instead of $_SESSION.

Comment: I do not have an error message because all I know is that the session is not available at some of my customers and then I also save the session id. That's what I check when the customer visits one page. As I said, I also save the session id when the error occurs and when I try to use his session id and put it in the url, so that the program uses the session id, I am logged in!